# how to invoke python script in jsp/servlet?

Tags: python, html, jsp, beautifulsoup

I am trying to invoke a python code for screen scraping (using Beautiful Soup) from my jsp servlet. Or it would also work if it can be directly invoked from the HTML.
Looked through few threads but couldn't get any solution.
What I want is to give the python program some arguments and want it to do some screen scrapping and return the result to jsp somehow.

Comment: What is screen scrapping? It sounds like something python scripts on a server will not be able to do on the client machine.

Comment: I basically I want the python script to parse some data from a given url, it is sometimes called web scrapping also.

Comment: you can go through [java Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) (excuse the version, google came up with that old link, hasn't changed much though, I think)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about web scraping which is pulling information from other websites.

You are not going to be able to do something like this in somebody's browser because it violates Javascript's same origin policy, AND there is no way a browser is going to let you download and execute a script on a client's computer.

You could just write a python script to do this for you and execute it yourself on your machine however.

Just be sure you are not violating web site's terms of service.

EDIT:

In that case I would recommend running the script on the command line, and then using the output of the program in the servlet to generate the responses you want.

Comment: I don't want to run the python on the client's machine. I want the python to work on the server, preferably communicating with my jsp servlets.